# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `container` supplied to `ForwardRef(Portal)` when I open Material UI menu

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, material-ui

I using using simple menu demo provided in Material UI demos. A warning is appeared when I open the menu for the first time on page as seen below.

[image]

Here is my code

```
const classes = useStyles();
const buttonRef = React.useRef();
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
const handleMenu = (event) => {
   setAnchorEl(true);
};
const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
};

<Button size="small" startIcon={<BreakIcon/>} ref={buttonRef} className={classes.primaryBgColor} aria-controls={anchorEl ? "simple-menu" : undefined} aria-haspopup="true" onClick={handleMenu}> Coaching
</Button>
<Menu id="simple-menu" anchorEl={()=> buttonRef.current} keepMounted open={Boolean(anchorEl)} onClose={handleClose} >
    <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Need help to resolve this.

Comment: What versions of React and Material-UI are you using?

Comment: React is 16.13.1 and Material UI is 4.9.10

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is somewhere else in your codebase. I tried to replicate your component code in a sandbox and it works fine and do not throw any such warning.

Sandbox here : https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-z3isq?file=/demo.js

Comment: Hey Varun, it will be nice if you would add the code in comment, as your link is not working